Can't read data out of SPI device using STM32F1
I am new to STM32 family and trying to work with an SPI chip (W25Q). It seems like the micro is sending the desired bytes to W25Q, but the chip does not respond. Now I have a question with the CLK line of SPI of STM21F1. In the logic analyzer I can see that the CLK pin generate pulses during Transmit and the clock stops once the bytes are sent. So my question is how the clock works with Receive part? Note that I am using HARDWARE DRIVEN SLAVE MANAGEMENT (PA4 of micro is driven the micro itself). Can anyone please give me a clue, if I am doing anything wrong and for which the W25Q won't respond?
This is my SPI init function
void SPI_Init(SPI_TypeDef *SPIx, GPIO_TypeDef * CSPort, uint32_t CSPin) {
    // SCK => PA5
    // MISO => PA6
    // MSIO => PA7
    // NSS => PA4
    if(SPIx == SPI1){
        // Enable alternate function clock
        RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_AFIOEN;
        //CLK
        GPIO_Init(GPIOA, 5, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_50MHZ, GPIO_CNF_AF_OUTPUT_PP);
        //MISO
        GPIO_Init(GPIOA, 6, GPIO_MODE_INPUT, GPIO_CNF_INPUT_FLOATING);
        //MOSI
        GPIO_Init(GPIOA, 7, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_50MHZ, GPIO_CNF_AF_OUTPUT_PP);
        //Don't remap SP1 pins
        AFIO->MAPR &= ~AFIO_MAPR_SPI1_REMAP;
        
        //Hardware or Software Driven NSS
        if(CSPort){
            SPIConfig[0].CSPort = CSPort;
            SPIConfig[0].CSPin = CSPin;
            //CS / NSS
            GPIO_Init(CSPort, CSPin, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_50MHZ, GPIO_CNF_GP_OUTPUT_PP);
        } else {
            SPIConfig[0].CSPort = NULL;
            SPIConfig[0].CSPin = 0;
            //CS / NSS
            GPIO_Init(GPIOA, 4, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_50MHZ, GPIO_CNF_AF_OUTPUT_PP);
        }
        //Enable SPI1
        RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_SPI1EN;
    } else {
        return;
    }
    
    //Mode: Master
    SPIx->CR1 |= SPI_CR1_MSTR;
    //Set BAUD rate
    SPIx->CR1 &= ~SPI_CR1_BR_0;
    SPIx->CR1 |= SPI_CR1_BR_1;
    SPIx->CR1 |= SPI_CR1_BR_2;
    //MSB first
    SPIx->CR1 &= ~(SPI_CR1_LSBFIRST);
    //Full duplex (Transmit/Receive)
    SPIx->CR1 &= ~(SPI_CR1_RXONLY);
    //Data format 8-bit
    SPIx->CR1 &= ~(SPI_CR1_DFF);
    
    if(CSPort) {
        SPIx->CR1 |= SPI_CR1_SSI;
        SPIx->CR1 |= SPI_CR1_SSM;
    } else {
        SPIx->CR1 &= ~SPI_CR1_SSM;
        SPIx->CR2 |= SPI_CR2_SSOE;
    }
    
    if(CSPort) {
        //SPI Enable
        SPIx->CR1 |= SPI_CR1_SPE;
    }
}

I am trying hardware driven NSS management.. I initialize SPI with this function call
SPI_Init(SPI1, NULL, 0);
Here is the screenshot of logic analyer that shows that the CS pin is driven low as long as SPI remains enable and clocks are generated as per the BAUD setup, but the W25Q does not respond..
Reset W25Q

Release power down

Trying to read device id

If anyone faced this situation please let me know.
I am building the circuitry on a veroboard and here are the pictures to give you an idea on how I am doing it.



Ping, Orange, Yellow and Grey wires are connect the MCU and SPI module

Since MISO & MOSI are separate pins, SPI transmits & receives at the same time. For every byte you send you also receive a byte. So physically, your SPI master has to transmit a byte for it to be able to receive a byte.

Hi @brhans that makes perfect sense, but as you see, There is no data on the MISO line, its mostly HIGH (0xFF). Is it the flash chip? Shall I try to replace it? Also I am doing it on a veroboard, can this be due to the connecting wires?

@RakeshMehta We don't know if you have connected the SPI memory correctly to MCU, or to power supplies, or the remaining pins. You need to show the schematics. The veroboard photo might be a good idea, random wiring jumping around through many inches may cause signal integrity issues which are not visible on logic analyzer.

@Justme photo added as requested

Do you send a 0x66 "Enable Reset" before you send the 0x99 "Reset"?

I am sending 0x66, but the logic analyzer see it as "F", No idea why...

@RakeshMehta 0x66 is letter 'f', so that's why.

Yep, sorry, dumb anwer..

For $4, probably worth trying another SPI flash breakout board: https://www.adafruit.com/product/5636

Let me double check @hcheung

You were absolutely right @hcheung, thanks for helping out... Please put your comment as answer so that I can accept it as the correct answer.

SPI is a communication protocol where you clock-out one byte on MOSI, you will clock-in one byte on the MISO at the same time.

You didn't mentioned which WQ25 chip you are using, but based on page 26 of WQ25128 datasheet, the command 0xAB is a 5-byte command as 0xAB <dummy> <dummy> <dummy> <id>, the id will be returned by the slave on the 5th byte. command 0x90 is a 6-byte command as 0x90, <dummy>, <dummy>, <dummy>, 0, <mf>, <id>, the slave started to return data on the 4-6th bytes.

From the logic analyser captures, it shows in both cases that it prematurely end the transmission.

The gnd solder joint on the W25QXX looks suspicious. Try re-soldering it and see if that helps.

Did it already, noticed it when I took the photo, shorten the wires further, but same result.
